# Which lens adapter should I use to mount an FD Olympus lens on an MFT Lumix G-series camera?

Tags: lens-adapter, olympus, micro-four-thirds, panasonic-lumix, four-thirds

I own a micro four-thirds Panasonic Lumix DMC-G7 mirrorless camera, and recently I purchased an old Olympus 40-150mm Zuiko ED Lens, which is not MFT. Though this lens is listed as compatible with my camera on Panasonic's website, I need to buy an adapter for it since it is a simple four thirds lens. There are numerous MFT-FD adapters on the internet, and I am not sure which are compatible with my specific requirements. Is there a particular adapter I should purchase for this, or will any FD-MFT adapter work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: I think your title has an error. You probably mean ED Olympus lens, not FD. In any case, an image of the lens might help us make sure of what it is.

Comment: @EricShain isn't ED just the designation for "extra low dispersion" elements? There are m.Zuiko lenses (e.g., 12-40/2.8) that are also designated "ED". m.Zuiko is used for mft lenses, but the ft lenses were still just Zuiko, which was _also_ used by the OM-mount lenses. I'm not sure there's a clear mft/ft designation, unlike Panasonic's D (4/3) vs. DG/G (µ4/3).

Comment: @inkista I understand. I was guessing the "FD" in the title was confusion with "ED". The tricky part is whether the lens is a "Zuiko" or "m.Zuiko". This is why I thought a picture of the lens would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the mount of both the camera and lens to find an appropriate adapter, if one exists.

- You state that the camera has a micro-four-thirds mount.
- You state that the lens has a (not micro) four-thirds mount.

  - FD is an old Canon mount. It is unlikely to be what you are looking for.
  - OM is an old full frame (not four-thirds) Olympus mount, also unlikely to be what you are looking for.

Based on the information you provided, **you need a four-thirds to micro-four-thirds adapter**. Such adapters *do* exist. However, because both mounts have "four thirds" in the name, numerous unsuitable adapters will be included in the search results. You can precede unwanted search terms with a `-` to exclude them, but it doesn't always work. For example:

- Ebay: [micro four thirds adapter (af, auto focus, autofocus) -(nikon, nikkor, canon, yashica, minolta, pentax, extension, konica, macro, cy, eos, ef, fd, om, m42, c, m39, l39, leica, t2, reversing, reverse)](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=micro+four+thirds+adapter+%28af%2C+auto+focus%2C+autofocus%29+-%28nikon%2C+nikkor%2C+canon%2C+yashica%2C+minolta%2C+pentax%2C+extension%2C+konica%2C+macro%2C+cy%2C+eos%2C+ef%2C+fd%2C+om%2C+m42%2C+c%2C+m39%2C+l39%2C+leica%2C+t2%2C+reversing%2C+reverse%29)
- Amazon: [micro four thirds adapter -nikon -nikkor -canon -yashica -minolta -pentax -extension -konica -macro -cy -eos -ef -fd -om -m42 -c -m39 -l39 -leica -t2 -reversing -reverse](https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=micro+four+thirds+adapter+-nikon+-nikkor+-canon+-yashica+-minolta+-pentax+-extension+-konica+-macro+-cy+-eos+-ef+-fd+-om+-m42+-c+-m39+-l39+-leica+-t2+-reversing+-reverse)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the [Olympus MMF-3](https://www.getolympus.com/us/en/mmf-3-adapter.html) Four Thirds to Micro Four-Thirds adapter. This will give you full electronic communication with the four-thirds lens so you can meter and autofocus the lens, although AF performance can vary, depending on the lens and the adapter.  There are several other options, (including the MMF-2, and MMF-1/Panasonic DMW-MA1, and Viltrox JY-43F).

The MMF-1/DMW-MA1 is the earliest version and is a bit bigger and heavier than the later versions. The MMF-2 was redesigned to be smaller/lighter/cheaper, and the MMF-3 added weatherproofing (and is the current version). Functionally, all three are equivalent as they're just doing passive passthrough of the electronic signals.

BTW, you do *not* have an FD lens, you have an **FT** (four-thirds) lens; FD/FL is an older manual-focus Canon SLR mount.

see also:

- https://www.apotelyt.com/photo-accessory/four-thirds-adapter
- https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3261186

Answer (score -3):

Here's a [OMD to Micro 4/3 adapter from Metabones](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1049190-REG/metabones_mbom_m43_bm1_olympus_om_mount_lens.html/?ap=y&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIyf_YjNPU3gIVWB-tBh181gbiEAYYASABEgIZ9_D_BwE&lsft=BI%3A514&smp=Y).  It takes the 35mm image circle and compresses it down to M43.  This concentrates the light thus giving you an additional stop.  For example, a 50mm f/1.8 lens would be seen by your M43 camera as 50mm f/1.2!

Comment: Metabones does make a Speedbooster adaptor, but not, I think the one you linked to which doesn’t have any optics. The Speedboosters are a lot more expensive.

Comment: An OM adapter won't work in this situation; OM is the manual film SLR mount for Olympus; four-thirds is the digital Olympus SLR mount, which uses the same 4/3"-format sensor size micro four-thirds uses. Four thirds uses a completely different bayonet mount; and has electronic communication that can be translated to micro four-thirds (OM does not).